# working with multiple employers at the same time

Tags: job-offer, employer-relations

Long story short, I work in IT as a Software Developer and I used to earn 85,000$ with company A, with 10 paid vacation days and average insurance premium about 120$ per month and other benefits etc. then recently I got laid off.

Then I join company B (Company B have Fed clients so I got security clearance- Fed project min 2 years project duration or more told by Company B), which is offering me 80k with 10 paid vacation and 180$ per month premium insurance other average benefits such as 401k, HSA etc. I don’t think raises are possible.

Just now I have received an offer for 69k from COMPANY C  it’s a Huge Company with more than 1,70,000 or more employees worldwide, 
Main benefits up to 8% match on 401k 1$ to 75%. 5000$ educataion benefit or 25000$ per year college education. Zero premium for hsa 
account. there are other small benefits like free gym and MS/MBA program will be taken care by company C but you have to be with them at least one year or get approval from project manager for education/certification etc.

I am stuck not sure what to do, I like Company B&C but got this small paycheck feeling if I join Comp C. on the other hand MS/MBA is awesome to get without paying anything.

If possible I am thinking to manage company B vs Company C at the same time.

And I know that Company C allow telecommute 2 days every week. So I am planning to manage Company C and Company B (20 hours /week)

Does anyone have any experience how to proceed on this one, please help shed some light?
How to ask one employer to allow me 20 hours/week and another employer full time 40 hours. I am confident that I can complete work on time if they allowed.

company C is huge and after completion of 1 year, you can enroll in to MS/MBA graduate program and company or manager will pay for your education from project funds for the  (books,tuition and fees) I don't have to pay anything upfront.(not even from salary)

Thanks for all your help, Both are expecting me to work during normal business hours, No- non-compete issues, C may or may not give occasional overtime but C allows telecommute, I am sure that I can complete all stuff company B/C wants. I just need a chance. I am ready to leave if Company B finds someone, It will take sometime for Company B to find right match and redo Security Clearance
Help!!!

Comment: This doesn't sound like a plausible scenario.  Why would B, who is seeking a full-time employee, want to hire you for only 20 hours/week?  And then find another part-time hire or another full-time hire and find more work to do?  And then, presumably, leave after a year since you're not going to pursue an advanced degree while holding down two jobs.  Are both B and C expecting you to work during normal business hours?  Is C going to expect that you do occasional overtime?  Are there going to be intellectual property/ non-compete issues?

Comment: Thanks for all your help,     Both are expecting me to work during normal business hours,         No- non-compete issues, C may or may not give occasional overtime but C allows telecommute, I am sure that I can complete all stuff company B/C wants. I just need a chance.          I  am ready to leave if Company B finds someone,          It will take sometime for Company B to find right match and redo Security Clearance.

Comment: Get some specifics on paying for graduate school. Do you have to pay upfront and then get reimbursed if you pass? What if your hours are so excessive that going to school is not practical? Find out how many people have and are currently taking the company up on this benefit. One job I applied for claimed "Free Parking" which was true if you could find an open space out on the street like everyone else.

Comment: It's a huge company and after completion of 1 year, you can enroll in to MS/MBA graduate program and company will pay for your (books,tuition and fees) I don't have to pay anything upfront.(not even from salary)

Comment: As you say it is a great opportunity to do an MS/MBA, but what would you do with company B if you work for both?

Comment: Have you considered asking Company C to increase your offer? Tell them you would really like to work for them, but you have other offers with much higher salaries.

Comment: And on another note, I think it is an EXTREMELY bad idea to try and juggle two jobs with more than 40 hours of total work a week. They are both going to expect you to be available during business hours, so there will most certainly be conflicts.

Comment: @DavidK and if one is SC cleared they are not going to look kindly on this.

Answer (score 7):

> Does anyone have any experience how to proceed on this one

When I have been in similar positions in the past, I weighed the pros and cons among the offers, made my decision, chose one, and never looked back.

These decisions are very personal, and only you can know enough about yourself, what's important to you, and the offers to decide.

> how to ask current/future employer to allow me 20 hours/week and
>   another employer full time 40 hours.

There is only one way - just ask both companies.

You are unlikely to get them both to agree for several reasons

- Seemingly neither want a part-timer.
- Most companies expect you to be able to work more hours occasionally, if the need arises. Committing to a 60-hour week among two employers makes that hard.
- Most employers simply wouldn't want to share an employee this way.

But you never know until you ask.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I am misuderstanding you. Are you proposing to "telecommute" 2 days a week for company C and really be working for company B at that point? That's what it sounds like. If so, this is a great way to get fired by both companies when the inevitable conflicts occur because both companies think they can schedule you for things at the same time.  This is fraud. You cannot work the same hours for two companies simultaneously. I can't put it more plainly than that.

If you are thinking of working fultime for company C and the 20 hours for company B after your work hours scheduled for company C and then go to school for a Master degree which is another 20-30 hours a week of work,  well that is a recipe for exhaustion and burnout.

I personally would go with company B and then look for a better company that will pay for the masters (Or negotiate this with company B) and get the salary back up to where it was. I am suggesting this only becasue it sounds as if you are currently not working (Use of the past tense discussing your salary at company A is why I think so.) and a job with a decent salary is a better place to start looking for. Company C is offering a ridiculously low salary in comparison.